# Automapper to map an interface based on the Ternary Operator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, linq-to-entities, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 7.0.1 version. I have a DTO class as:

```
public class Dto1{
    public IModel Model {get;set;}
}

public interface IModel {}

public class QuestionA: IModel {
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class QuestionB: IModel {
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

During creating Linq to Entity, I encounter a condition and based on condition I have to create the object of QuestionA class or ClassB. My Mapping is like:

```
CreatMap<SourceClass, Dto1>()  
      .ForMember(d=> d.Model, opt=> opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type == 0 ? 
                 new QuestionA()
                 {  
                     Text = src.Text
                 } : new QuestionB()
                 {
                     Id = src.Id
                 }));
```

I am unable to achieve this behavior. I am getting runtime exception as:

**Unable to cast the type 'QuestionA' to type 'IQuestionTypeModel'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**

Comment: Did you try to cast to `IModel` inside `MapFrom` expression? like `(IModel) new QuestionA()`

Comment: Yes! It didn't work though

Comment: Please update the question with code showing how you use AutoMapper along with the query you are executing. I tried with EF Core and local SQL server using AutoMapper Queryable Extensions `ProjectTo()` and I failed to reproduce the error you are having. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Both ends of Ternary Operator must return the same type. Despite the fact, that both `QuestionA` and `QuestionB` implement `IModel`, you need to explicitly mark them as the same type:

```cs
CreateMap<SourceClass, Dto1>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Model,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
            src.Type == 0
            ? new QuestionA() { Text = src.Text } as IModel
            : new QuestionB() { Id = src.Id } as IModel));
```

---

#### EDIT #1

I tried locally with a SQL Server, with the above configuration and AutoMapper Querable Extensions `ProjectTo()`:

```cs
var result = dbContext
    .Set<SourceClass>()
    .ProjectTo<Dto1>(configuration)
    .ToList();
```

And I've recieved valid results. EF Core generated such query:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN [s].[Type] = 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, [s].[Text], [s].[Id]
FROM [SourceClass] AS [s]
```

Comment: No! it doe not work too, because Linq to entities throwing error The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'QuestionA' and a check of type 'IModel' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.